# Baumslag–Solitar $B(1,2)$ is not hyperbolic

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

I have a question which asks me to show that the Baumslag–Solitar $B(1,2)$ is not hyperbolic by considering its Cayley graph and showing that triangles can be arbitrarily fat.

The Cayley graph can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group).

My idea is to pick two points arbitrarily far to the right in the graph and pick two points that are k-distance apart then "move up one level" and pick two vertices there.

Then my geodesic triangle will have one side that can be k+1 large but the other 2 will be short (only length 1) hence by increasing k I can just increase how fat my triangle is.

Is this the correct approach and can anybody help me make it more precise?

Thanks for any help

Comment: That is the right idea, but you need to know that you just didn't pick a crappy path.  Do you know what a "staggered" group presentation is and what it implies?

Comment: @N.Owad No, could you give me reference/ explain to me?

Comment: @hmmm Magnus, Karrass and Solitar is the standard reference for such presentations - they occur when you do Magnus' method (before the modified HNN-method came along). Look at their section on the word problem for 1-relator groups.

Comment: Geodesic triangles are the usual definition but this is not the most natural way to check non-hyperbolicity.

Comment: It is much easier to observe that linear isoperimetric inequality is violated by these groups.

Comment: Actually, the work to verify nonlinear isoperimetric inequality and the work to construct a fat triangle as in my answer are pretty similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method will not work, it is not possible for a triangle to have two sides of length 1 and one side of large length, because that is a violation of the triangle inequality.

Instead what you can do (referring to [the same picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aBaumslag-Solitar_Cayley_3D.svg)) is to take a point $x$ on the upper left edge, and to take two points $y,y'$ on the upper right edge, so that the distance between $y,y'$ is small, even as small as $1$. Then construct two geodesics $xy$, $xy'$: each of them starts from $x$, then goes downward in [the picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aBaumslag-Solitar_Cayley_3D.svg), then turns back upward at the lowest level. The geodesic $xy$ turns back upward at a point $z$ at the lowest level, and the geodesic $xy'$ turns back upward at a point $z'$ also at the same lowest level. The trick is to see that $xy$, $xy'$ can be chosen so that the distance between $z,z'$ is large. Then to make the triangle fatter and fatter, choose $x$ further up to the left, and choose $y,y'$ further up to the right.

That's kind of vague, but if you can figure out the picture that I am trying to convey using much fewer than a thousand words, then it should quickly become clear.